# MouseMotionListener on MouseDragged Only Returns The Component The Drag Started On

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to make a lock screen program which is a JFrame that contains multiple JPanels inside. I have added a MouseMotionListener in each panel (Cell) class. I would like it so that the user can drag the mouse and be able to drag into multiple cells. The problem is that MouseEvent.GetSource (casted to a cell) is only returning the cell that the drag started from. Here's my code.

```
public class Cell extends JPanel {

    public String name;

    public Cell(String name, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                onMouseOver(e);
            }
        });
        setBackground(color);
        setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }

    private void onMouseOver(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain "drag into multiple cells"  ?

Comment: @Berger I mean drag the mouse from one cell to another.

Comment: So you want all the cells that have been hovered over during the drag movement ?

Comment: @Berger Yes, as of now it's only returning the cell the drag movement started from. I don't think i'm doing anything wrong as the javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) says that it won't change the cell regardless of if the mouse is within the components bounds or not. I need some sort of alternate way of doing this.

Comment: You may add a `boolean selected;` in `Cell` then when a cell recieves a `mouseDragged` , set this value to `true`. Finally when you need the whole list, check the `selected` value of each cell .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that MouseEvent.GetSource (casted to a cell) is only returning the cell that the drag started from

That is correct. All events will be relative to the cell that you clicked on when dragging started.

If you want to know what cell you are currently over then you need to do the calculation yourself.

So you can use `getPoint()` method from the MouseEvent and then calculate the component you are over.

So for example you could convert the point to the parent container using the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method.

Then once you have the Point relative to the parent container you can find the current component on the container using the `Container.findComponentAt(...)` method.

You will need to keep track of every component you find. Maybe add the component to a `Set`.

Or, instead of adding the listener to every cell. You could just add the listener to the parent panel. Then all the points will be relative to the panel so you won't need to convert point, just do the `findComponentAt(...)` logic.

Comment: I'm using the findComponentAt method and it works perfectly! Thank you for the help!